# Excel conert seconds dd hh mm ss for larger value

Tags: excel, datetime

I am trying to convert seconds to dd hh:mm:ss format
 I am using the formula:

```
=A1/(24*60*60)
```

For 1099014 I get the result 12 17:16:54

For 2198028 I get the result 25 10:33:48

But for 3297042 I get the result 07 03:50:42

And the value for which I need the result is 7473837 and I get the result 26 12:03:57 which I suppose is not correct.

So why does the value fluctuates like this in excel and how can I exactly calculate the correct value?

Thank You

Answer (score 3, accepted):

3,297,042 seconds represents 38 days 03:50:42

If you extend you format to have the whole date: `yyyy MM dd hh:mm:ss`

You'll see: `1900 02 07 03:50:42`

That's why your format string gives you `07 03:50:42`

Same thing for 7,473,837 where date is `1900 03 26 12:03:57`

I might be wrong, but it seems there's no format (like [h] for hours) to tell excel to diplay number of days. Instead you could use:

`=INT(A1/86400) & TEXT(A1/86400," hh:mm:ss")`